# CSS3 & PHP lightbox with thumbs for updating video content daily

Tags: php, css, slider, thumbnails

Ok, so I'm trying to implement a sliding video thumb gallery linked to a lightbox similar to the home page of [reason.com](http://www.reason.com) but I would like to do it in pure CSS if possible.  I already have the code complete for the lightbox which is basically pure CSS with a `javascript:void` function linking thumbs to the lightbox.

My issue is that I plan on updating the videos daily since it is for an article database and would rather not have to capture the video thumbs for every video upon updating.

Is there a way to dynamically capture thumbs of videos with a PHP script and including the script in my `javascript:void` link that will display the thumb for my lightbox?  I'm basically trying to find a work around for capturing and resizing the thumbs for all of the videos in my thumb slider because this would be increasingly teadious to do on a daily basis.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

CSS:

```
.black_alpha{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0%;
     left: 0%;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: black;
     z-index:1001;
     -moz-opacity: 0.8;
     opacity:.80;
     filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
     .video {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 25%;
     left: 25%;
     width: 50%;
     height: 50%;
     padding: 16px;
     border: 16px solid orange;
     background-color: white;
     z-index:1002;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
**I want each thumb to link  to this** <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = 
"document.getElementById('light').style.display='block'document.getElementById
('fade').style.display='block'"> 

<div id="light" class="video"> **this should show the video of the thumb clicked**
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></div>

<div id="fade" class="black_alpha"></div>

</body>
```

I thought the thumb slider would have been irrelevant so I didn't include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to [capture images from video](http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/). It's easy to use and just needs to be installed on your server. You can run the ffmpeg commands from php using [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) (note: this may need to be enabled in your php.ini)

Comment: Lol I just found someone's example of doing exactly that, http://blog.amnuts.com/2007/06/22/create-a-random-thumbnail-of-a-video-file/ my question is how to implement this within a web page to upload vids for ppl that don't have any coding experience bc I work with ppl who write content and don't know a lick of code..hmm

Comment: try using the <form> element with some <input> elements :)

Comment: I've never used ffmpeg, wondering how I install it on my server?  Do I just extract the folder to the root dir or do I need to edit my php.ini file?

Comment: If you are on a shared host, contact your provider and they'll be happy to install it. Once it is installed, you'll see it listed when you call phpinfo(). If you have your own server, check these links: http://mysql-apache-php.com/ffmpeg-install.htm http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-install-ffmpeg-linux